# Create hidden column in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, security

Can we create hidden column in the table. It should be listed  only  when  I specify column name explicitly in select statement.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You clearly think that a "hidden column" is the solution but the solution to what problem?

Comment: I have been asked to confirm that does postgresql has such feature as part of my solution. So, just wanted to know whether it has or not. and to my knowledge I have also never heard this feature is in postgresql. Or What can be the convincing answer to them.

Comment: @Pavunkumar You should go back to whoever's asking and ask them "why? What for? What problem is that going to solve for you?"

Comment: A simple use case is getting a more flexible schema design into your database. For example, if application A does a `SELECT *` today and application B wants to add a new field, application A would most likely fail because it gets an additional column back it doesn't expect. The app shouldn't do a `SELECT *` in the first place but such things happen and when you don't have control over the code, such as with a third-party application, you get a lot of problems and then even views can't help. http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADMIN/managing-tables.htm#GUID-38DBFC2E-FC6C-46E2-A7A1-6FA703F9DC01

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can effectively do this by creating a view and selecting only the columns you wish to show.

Comment: *headdesk*. I didn't think to suggest that. In PostgreSQL, simple views are updatable too, so they appear just like a table to most applications.

Comment: But that column would still show up when you run a `select *` on the base table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not if you don't `GRANT` the `SELECT` right on the base table. Look into `security_barrier` views. 9.4 adds support for simply updatable security barrier views; in older versions you can use rule- or trigger-based updatable views. Or if you don't mind the potential information leakage via malicious predicates, just use an ordinary view - if a user has the right to select from a view, they implicitly gain the right to select the columns of the underlying table via the view, so you don't have to explicitly `GRANT` access to the table.

Comment: Have you tried this?  Postgres does not seem to support views without all the columns.

Comment: @Pyrolistical I'm not sure I understand your comment - under what scenario could you not create a view with whatever columns you choose to include? (And yes, I have tried this :-) )

Comment: My bad.  Postgres does not support replacing and existing views with less columns.  You need to drop it and create it again.  (create or replace view does not work)

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no supported and safe way to create a hidden column that's listed only when you specify the column name explicitly. PostgreSQL doesn't provide any user-accessible way to hide user-defined columns from the `*` wildcard.

You could use any user interface layer / query builder of your choice to do this, though.

(PostgreSQL actually *does* have hidden columns, as you'll see if you `select ctid,xmin,xmax from some_table`, but it doesn't allow users to add to the set of hidden columns. It is possible to modify the system catalogs directly to trick PostgreSQl into thinking that a user defined column is a hidden system column, but it's a *really bad idea* to mess directly with the catalogs, so I won't explain how in detail. If you insist on doing this, read the documentation on `pg_attribute` ... but understand that you're creating a giant foot gun.).

You *can* set column permissions so a user can only select some columns, though again you can't say "all except this one", you have to say "I want them to be able to see these ones".

Update: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan has the most sensible suggestion: *you probably want a view*. Mark that answer as correct, not mine.

Comment: Is it being supported by any other database.?

Comment: @Pavunkumar I don't have an encyclopedic knowledge of other databases. I don't know of any with the feature, but then, I've never wanted it either so I wouldn't have looked.

Comment: @Pavunkumar, MariaDB now includes support for invisible columns. (But MariaDB didn't exist when you asked that question, and its forerunner MySQL didn't support this feature.)

Comment: Hidden (invisible) columns are available in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-columns.html) as of version 8.0.23.